How to project an unseen vector to the lower rank SVD subspace?
I think I might be missing something fundamental when it comes to SVD, or perhaps the answer to my question actually isn't straightforward.
Say we have a Matrix $A$ of rank n. SVD, as far as I understand, would give us the closest k-rank approximation of A by factorising it into 3 different matrices:
$$A = UΣV^{T} $$
From the point of view of representation learning or Machine learning in general, rows of U and columns of V, respectively are essentially the k-dimensional embeddings for the entities represented by the rows and columns of $A$. Say $A$ is the matrix representing n rows(users) and m columns(items) and
$A_{ij} = $ some score metric for user i and item j.
This essentially means a row of A represents a user and a column represents a particular item. Then $U$ gives us embeddings for the users and $V$ the embeddings for the items in the underlying k-dimensional subspace such that the user-item dot products correspond to their original score in $A$ as closely as possible. Hence, it could be said that this underlying k-dimensional subspace is the optimal space to project the user/item vectors to for the purpose of figuring out a user-item score(correct me if I'm wrong).
My question is, given a new user or item vector similar to the ones present in $A$, how can one project it to this underlying k-dimensional subspace found by SVD to get it's optimal embedding?

As I understand it, SVD is not row-wise or column-wise operation. It approximates the entire matrix $A$. The approximation is derived in the context of the entire dataset $A$. In applications, assuming centered data, you can apply SVD to the covariance matrix $A^TA$ to find the directions in the data along which the data varies the most. Then if you get a new vector, you can zero out the directions where the data doesn't vary much.
